# SQLite net PCL - Simple select

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, portable-class-library

I use SQLite from windows app and now I am developing in Xamarin a portable app so I am using the plugin sqlite net pcl and I am having great trouble to understand how it works.

I have a table that is created by te following:

```
public class Config
    {
        public string IP { get; set; }
        [SQLite.Net.Attributes.Default(true, "Client 2")]
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }
```

and to create the table:

```
db.CreateTable<Model.Config>();
```

Problem: Now I want to select the value in ID column and I do the following:

```
List<string> hhid = db.Query<string>("select ID from Config",null);
```

I get this exception: `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"`

How can I make a simple select to find this field?

Thanks for any tip

Comment: `List<string> hhid = db.Query<string>("select id from Config",null);` the field name is `ID` not `id` change the Select to match the field name

Comment: @MethodMan I tried that and same result. I updated the question now

Comment: Is `db` properly initialized?

Comment: Have you tried the LINQ syntax instead of the .Query ? i.e. https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL. `conn.Table<Config>();`

Comment: @nachogsiri Did you solve it?

Comment: @voytek Yes, there I posted an answer. Tell me if you have problems

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hoping this will be usefull to someone in my place...

Between the brackets (<>) goes the table name:

```
db.Query<TableName>("select * from ....");
```

### Some examples that worked for me:

#### Simple select:

```
var list = db.Query<MyTableName>("select * from MyTableName");
```

#### Select with restrictions:

```
var list = db.Query<MyTableName>("select * from MyTableName where lastname=? and firstname=?", lastnameValue, firstNameValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't really help if you have a custom mapping for the tables name.
The "Sql" table name can be found at runtime accessing to the type mapping.

Here an extension method

```
public static class NativeConnectionExtension
{
    public static List<T> SelectAllFrom<T>(this SQLiteConnection cnn) where T : new()
    {
        var mapping = cnn.GetMapping<T>();
        var result = cnn.Query<T>(String.Format("select * from {0};", mapping.TableName));
        return result;
    }
}
```