# SQLite PCL for VB.NET, How to Query?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I've seen many exmples of this being used in C# to query using  attribute to reference the table mapping. This does not work in Visual basic. Does anyone know how to query the SQLite Database?

Example here: [SQLite net PCL - Simple select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30742167/sqlite-net-pcl-simple-select)

The Below code is an example of what I have, yet this does not work

```
custs = db.Query(lcCust)("SELECT lcCust.* FROM lcCust")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the original C#

```
class MyTableName
{
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
}

var list = db.Query<MyTableName>("select * from MyTableName");
var list = db.Query<MyTableName>("select * from MyTableName where lastname=? and firstname=?", lastnameValue, firstNameValue);
```

and translated to VB.net

```
Class MyTableName
{
    Public Property lastname As String
    Public Property firstname As String
}
Dim list = db.Query(Of MyTableName)("select * from MyTableName")
Dim list = db.Query(Of MyTableName)("select * from MyTableName where lastname=? and firstname=?", lastnameValue, firstNameValue)
```

Comment: Perfect, I realised I had to make a class to map to also, Thank you